# document.documentElement.scrollTop return value differs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to process some code based on the '`document.documentElement.scrollTop`' value. It returns '`348`' in FF and IE but in Chrome it returns '`0`'. Do i need to do anything to overcome this issue?

FF:

```
>>> document.documentElement.scrollTop
342
```

Chrome:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop
0
```

Comment: Try `document.body.scrollTop`

Comment: Thanks @Passerby.. is there any other solution other that this? If not, i have to go by this way.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...Generally you can use `(document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop)`.

Comment: hmm.. cross-browser-wise should be: `(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) ||  document.body.scrollTop;`

Comment: The suggestions are great, except when trying to set the scroll position...

Answer (score 51):

The standards-based way of getting the scroll is [`window.scrollY`](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-window-scrolly).  This is supported by Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE Edge or later.  If you only support these browsers, you should go with this property.

IE >= 9 supports a similar property `window.pageYOffset`, which for the sake of compatibility returns the same as `window.scrollY` in recent browsers, though it may perhaps be deprecated at some point.

The problem with using `document.documentElement.scrollTop` or `document.body.scrollTop` is that the scroll needn't be defined on either of these.  Chrome and Safari define their scroll on the `<body>` element  whilst Firefox defines it on the `<html>` element returned by `document.documentElement`, for example.  This is not standardized, and could potentially change in future versions of the browsers.  However, if the `scrollY` or `pageYOffset` are not present, this is the only way to get the scroll.

TL;DR:

`window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop + (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0)`

Comment: returns `NaN` in chrome 46

Comment: Works fine for me on chrome 47...  Does your problem occur on any particular site or all sites?

Comment: @jazmit: what is the usage of this part of the condition document.body.scrollTop + (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || 0)

Comment: The scroll can be defined on either `document.body` or `document.documentElement`.  Theoretically, it could be defined on both, so we use addition to combine the scrolls. `documentElement` may not be defined at all, thus the || 0 default.

Comment: if its defined mean? sure we know that the document.body.scrollTop and document.documentElement.scrollTop is not going to present in same time. so y we need the concatenation here...i m not able to understand

Comment: y dont we give like this 
window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop ||  document.documentElement.scrollTop

Comment: how does scrollY compare to `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop`?

Answer (score 19):

Try this

```
window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

Comment: Fun fact: this doesn't always work in a WebView in Windows Phone. Esoteric edge case, but something I just slammed into. Those numbers are sometimes different, emphasis on the sometimes, and the pageYOffset appears to be wrong when they are.

Comment: Thanks pal, that fixed an issue I had with Safari

Answer (score 3):

**You can just use the following codes to fix that bug!**

```js
let scrollHeight = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
console.log(`scrollHeight = ${scrollHeight}`);


/*

this comment just using for testing the scroll height!

but in this iframe, it doesn't work at all!

So, you can try it out using Chrome console!

*/
```

> **document.body.scrollTop;**
> // For Chrome, Safari and Opera
> **document.documentElement.scrollTop;**
> // Firefox and IE places the overflow at the  level, unless else is specified.
> Therefore, we use the documentElement property for these two browsers

**reference links:**
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-scrolltop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Answer (score 3):

Use [window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY) where possible, it's designed to be consistent across browsers. If you need to support IE, then I'd recommend the following to only use `window.scrollY` if it's available:

```
typeof window.scrollY === "undefined" ? window.pageYOffset : window.scrollY
```

`window.scrollY` will be evaluated as false if it returns 0, so doing `window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset` would technically check `window.pageYOffset` whenever `window.scrollY` were 0, which obviously isn't ideal if `window.pageYOffset` did not also equal 0.

Also note that if you need to get the scroll value frequently (every frame/every scroll) as is often the case, you might want to check if `window.scrollY` is defined beforehand. I like to use this small helper function I wrote to do exactly that, along with using `requestAnimationFrame` - it should work in IE10 and up.

```
function registerScrollHandler (callback) {
    "use strict"

    var useLegacyScroll = typeof window.scrollY === "undefined",
        lastX = useLegacyScroll ? window.pageXOffset : window.scrollX,
        lastY = useLegacyScroll ? window.pageYOffset : window.scrollY

    function scrollHandler () {
        // get the values using legacy scroll if we need to
        var thisX = useLegacyScroll ? window.pageXOffset : window.scrollX,
            thisY = useLegacyScroll ? window.pageYOffset : window.scrollY

        // if either the X or Y scroll position changed
        if (thisX !== lastX || thisY !== lastY) {
            callback(thisX, thisY)

            // save the new position
            lastX = thisX
            lastY = thisY
        }

        // check again on the next frame
        window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollHandler)
    }

    scrollHandler()
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
registerScrollHandler(function (x, y) {
    /* your code here :) */
    console.log("Scrolled the page", x, y)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function
[`document.body.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) 
 and it returns this object `{x: 0, y: 0, width: 1903, height: 2691.5625, top: 0, …};` in this object you can access body top `document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using the Safari version 13 or the lower version. Please update your Safari browser to 14 or higher.