# Programmatically scroll with non-integral scale values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, scale

Chrome 65.0.3325.181 on Windows 10.0.16299.309. Monitor: 27″, 3840×2160.

Display scaled to 150%, typing in Chrome’s console:

> ```
> document.documentElement.scrollTop = 1
> 1
> document.documentElement.scrollTop
> 0.6666666865348816
> ```

[image: Chrome console]

> ```
> document.documentElement.scrollTop = 9
> 9
> document.documentElement.scrollTop
> 8.666666984558105
> ```

Another test with [`window.scrollBy(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) and [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY), starting at the top of the page:

```
(function f() {
  scrollBy(0, 1)
  console.log(scrollY)
  if (scrollY < 10) {
    f()
  }
})()
```

Output (15 lines – factor of 1.5 of the expected number):

```
0.6666666865348816
1.3333333730697632
2
2.6666667461395264
3.3333332538604736
4
4.666666507720947
5.333333492279053
6
6.666666507720947
7.333333492279053
8
8.666666984558105
9.333333015441895
10
```

Yet another test with [`window.scroll(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll):

```
(function f(n) {
  scroll(0, n)
  console.log(scrollY)
  if (scrollY < 10) {
    f(n + 1)
  }
})(1)
```

Output (10 lines – as expected because of no accumulation):

```
0.6666666865348816
2
2.6666667461395264
4
4.666666507720947
6
6.666666507720947
8
8.666666984558105
10
```

Display scaled to 125%:

> ```
> document.documentElement.scrollTop = 1
> 1
> document.documentElement.scrollTop
> 0.800000011920929
> ```

It seems to me that the value that is really set is “calculated” by `value - 1 + 1/scale` if `value * scale` is not integral.

Is that a bug on my site, Windows’s or Chrome’s?

Comment: It looks more like it's 100/scale.

Comment: @nixkuroi I should have mentioned that e.g. 9 results in 8.666666984558105. And it's the inverse of `scale`, not `scale` itself.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514596/document-documentelement-scrolltop-return-value-differs-in-chrome ?

Comment: @nixkuroi Doesn't help me, unfortunately. I have the exact same problem with [`window.scroll(0, 1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll): `window.scrollY === 0.6666666865348816`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why aren't you adding ".px" to your scrollTop?

Comment: @nixkuroi `scrollTop` is a numeric property which represents pixels.

Comment: Understood.  I've seen browser compatibility issues around that before, but maybe those are all ironed out by now.