# Window Scroll event doesn't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have set up a simple function to add a class to header when scrolling some amounts of pixels from the top of the document, it works everywhere but not in Edge. Any ideas why that is ?

No errors in the console, nothing, just doesn't work.

```
const headerScrollClass = () => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(callback, 100));
}

function throttle(fn, wait) {
  let time = Date.now();
  return function () {
    if ((time + wait - Date.now()) < 0) {
      fn();
      time = Date.now();
    }
  }
}

const callback = () => {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.querySelector('.header').classList.add('header--top');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.header').classList.remove('header--top');
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably because it isn't supported, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514596/document-documentelement-scrolltop-return-value-differs-in-chrome/33462363 basically, make sure `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is giving you what you think it is giving you

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Huangism said, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` seems not supported by Microsoft Edge. You could try [the example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollleft4) in w3schools. You'll find that if you only use `document.documentElement`, it will not work in Edge. So I think you should use `document.body.scrollTop` in Edge.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

You could try the following code to make it compatible in different browsers:

```
var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset 
            || document.documentElement.scrollTop  
            || document.body.scrollTop  
            || 0;
```