# Show Button only particular area while scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to show Button between 370px to 410px while scrolling in the Page.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      try {
        if ((document.body.scrollTop < 410 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 410) && (document.body.scrollTop > 370 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 370)) {
          setBtn(true);
        } else {
          setBtn(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    });
  }, [Btn]);
```

```
{Btn ? <button>Submit</button> : null}
```

Suggest me, how to solve this because this above code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your validation is that using an `||` operator using two ways of getting the `scrollTop` is causing your issues, because in chrome `document.body.scrollTop` returns 0, and that guarantees that the first part of your condition will always be true. So you need to separate for each way of getting the `scrollTop`

In other words, your if should have this instead:

```
((document.body.scrollTop < 410 && document.body.scrollTop > 370) || (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 410 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 370))
```

Also [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462363/9801177) a better explanation of the `scrollTop` problem