# Move element on scroll event on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, scrolltop

I want to move an element on scroll event. 
My code works fine on chrome but not on firefox.

```
$body = $(document.body);

$(window).scroll(function () { 

$( "#topHeadVal" ).css('top', $body.scrollTop());    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3cee7e2m/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get scrollTop() to work in both Chrome & Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778020/cant-get-scrolltop-to-work-in-both-chrome-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of $body.scrollTop(), here is the result http://jsfiddle.net/3cee7e2m/5/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/3cee7e2m/2/

Use `$(document)` instead of `$(document.body)`.

Also, your example code makes me concerned. If you're trying to stick something to a fixed position on the screen, are you sure you're not looking for the `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `$body` with `$(window)` and it worked:

```
$( "#topHeadVal" ).css('top','27px');
var $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function () { 
    $( "#topHeadVal" ).css('top', $window.scrollTop());
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3cee7e2m/3/)