# Body set to position absolute can't get or set scrollTop() in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following JS fiddle, clicking the link in the right hand side bar will scroll the page to 400px down in Firefox but it doesn't work in Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/a4qx507f/9/

For argument's sake, let's say that I probably can't change the HTML or CSS, is there a way in JS to get this working?

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

In Chrome, following returns 0 no matter how far you scroll down.

```
console.log($('body').scrollTop());
```

In Chrome, following does nothing

```
$('body').scrollTop(400);
```

Both work in Firefox.

Comment: I've got same issue, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778118/6850886) answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `overflow: hidden;` on your `html` selector. If you remove that it works as expected, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4qx507f/10/

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute in the body attributes and then try with
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 400 }, "slow");

Sorry I didn´t see the title... my answer doesn´t work width absolute position

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a4qx507f/12/

Wrap your overflowed content inside content div

```
<div id="content">
  <button class="btn">Get scroll Top</button>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
   .....
  </p>
</div>
```

And add this CSS to `#content`

```
#content{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

and remove `overflow-y: scroll` from the `body`

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #c0ffee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  console.log($('body').scrollTop());
  console.log($('#top-pos').position().top);
})

$('#scroll').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#content').scrollTop(400);


})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #c0ffee;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
}

#top-pos {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
}

#content{
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <h4>Sidebar</h4>
  <a id="scroll" href>Click to scroll</a>
</div>
<div id="top-pos"></div>
<div id="content">
  <button class="btn">Get scroll Top</button>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan porta sollicitudin. Duis vitae libero pellentesque, dapibus nunc nec, egestas purus. Sed ultrices at ipsum vel dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ligula sem, condimentum ut eleifend
    ut, pharetra a quam. Curabitur sed fringilla velit. Nullam placerat justo sed nisi venenatis aliquet. In odio libero, faucibus sed velit nec, accumsan iaculis justo. Vestibulum vel rhoncus sapien. Fusce a convallis sapien. Pellentesque eu luctus orci.
    Aliquam dictum massa eget nunc feugiat, eu tempor urna feugiat. Proin ornare magna sed magna venenatis, sit amet gravida ipsum ullamcorper. Vivamus sit amet turpis maximus, venenatis metus quis, facilisis felis. Donec maximus, mi vitae tempor tincidunt,
    nibh nulla dapibus tellus, sit amet aliquam eros mi quis odio. Integer sodales elit sodales ante tempus, ac posuere nisi pellentesque.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis ut porttitor nisl. Fusce laoreet sodales justo, eu consectetur lacus malesuada ut. Etiam tempus leo id est vestibulum, non finibus tortor dignissim. In nunc dui, volutpat at rhoncus ut, sollicitudin vel libero. Nulla eget nisl imperdiet, varius odio
    vel, pellentesque urna. Donec ornare commodo augue, non malesuada tortor eleifend et. Maecenas sollicitudin fringilla ex, ac aliquam lacus mollis vel. Maecenas faucibus hendrerit purus in laoreet. Nulla maximus varius risus eu sagittis. In urna quam,
    iaculis lacinia turpis eu, consectetur congue sapien. Curabitur eget efficitur eros.
  </p>
  <h1 id="test">Scroll to here.</h1>
  <p>
    Sed dictum nulla vitae sapien ornare lacinia. Curabitur eu augue in libero sodales cursus. Sed in consectetur augue. Curabitur vitae sagittis arcu, id malesuada felis. Curabitur efficitur non risus ut placerat. Aliquam commodo rutrum eleifend. Mauris
    a consectetur est. Maecenas semper justo non tristique porta. In eget mauris augue.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed lacus mi, ultrices ac condimentum sed, eleifend id est. Aenean dapibus sem libero, eget dapibus odio varius sed. Praesent ac elit porta, aliquet tortor ac, aliquet mauris. Sed pharetra tellus sed nunc euismod, ut euismod quam tempus. Nunc rhoncus
    diam ut commodo faucibus. Curabitur et diam vel nulla porta viverra semper nec velit. Donec placerat mi consectetur tortor porta, ac dignissim tellus sollicitudin. Ut viverra sem ut aliquam vulputate. Morbi sagittis viverra commodo. Suspendisse arcu
    sem, consectetur non aliquam id, blandit sit amet quam. In cursus nisl et fermentum eleifend. Curabitur nec imperdiet purus, vel dapibus lorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Pellentesque et purus ac nisi suscipit feugiat id nec risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean ornare scelerisque congue. Duis ac velit et metus suscipit auctor. Cras et tellus et ante vehicula
    tincidunt quis at sem. Nunc pharetra et lorem sit amet varius. Proin ultrices, sapien a feugiat ornare, augue enim pretium velit, ac vehicula nibh diam convallis tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
    turpis egestas.
  </p>
  <button class="btn">Get scroll Top</button>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan porta sollicitudin. Duis vitae libero pellentesque, dapibus nunc nec, egestas purus. Sed ultrices at ipsum vel dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ligula sem, condimentum ut eleifend
    ut, pharetra a quam. Curabitur sed fringilla velit. Nullam placerat justo sed nisi venenatis aliquet. In odio libero, faucibus sed velit nec, accumsan iaculis justo. Vestibulum vel rhoncus sapien. Fusce a convallis sapien. Pellentesque eu luctus orci.
    Aliquam dictum massa eget nunc feugiat, eu tempor urna feugiat. Proin ornare magna sed magna venenatis, sit amet gravida ipsum ullamcorper. Vivamus sit amet turpis maximus, venenatis metus quis, facilisis felis. Donec maximus, mi vitae tempor tincidunt,
    nibh nulla dapibus tellus, sit amet aliquam eros mi quis odio. Integer sodales elit sodales ante tempus, ac posuere nisi pellentesque.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis ut porttitor nisl. Fusce laoreet sodales justo, eu consectetur lacus malesuada ut. Etiam tempus leo id est vestibulum, non finibus tortor dignissim. In nunc dui, volutpat at rhoncus ut, sollicitudin vel libero. Nulla eget nisl imperdiet, varius odio
    vel, pellentesque urna. Donec ornare commodo augue, non malesuada tortor eleifend et. Maecenas sollicitudin fringilla ex, ac aliquam lacus mollis vel. Maecenas faucibus hendrerit purus in laoreet. Nulla maximus varius risus eu sagittis. In urna quam,
    iaculis lacinia turpis eu, consectetur congue sapien. Curabitur eget efficitur eros.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed dictum nulla vitae sapien ornare lacinia. Curabitur eu augue in libero sodales cursus. Sed in consectetur augue. Curabitur vitae sagittis arcu, id malesuada felis. Curabitur efficitur non risus ut placerat. Aliquam commodo rutrum eleifend. Mauris
    a consectetur est. Maecenas semper justo non tristique porta. In eget mauris augue.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed lacus mi, ultrices ac condimentum sed, eleifend id est. Aenean dapibus sem libero, eget dapibus odio varius sed. Praesent ac elit porta, aliquet tortor ac, aliquet mauris. Sed pharetra tellus sed nunc euismod, ut euismod quam tempus. Nunc rhoncus
    diam ut commodo faucibus. Curabitur et diam vel nulla porta viverra semper nec velit. Donec placerat mi consectetur tortor porta, ac dignissim tellus sollicitudin. Ut viverra sem ut aliquam vulputate. Morbi sagittis viverra commodo. Suspendisse arcu
    sem, consectetur non aliquam id, blandit sit amet quam. In cursus nisl et fermentum eleifend. Curabitur nec imperdiet purus, vel dapibus lorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Pellentesque et purus ac nisi suscipit feugiat id nec risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean ornare scelerisque congue. Duis ac velit et metus suscipit auctor. Cras et tellus et ante vehicula
    tincidunt quis at sem. Nunc pharetra et lorem sit amet varius. Proin ultrices, sapien a feugiat ornare, augue enim pretium velit, ac vehicula nibh diam convallis tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
    turpis egestas.
  </p>
  <button class="btn">Get scroll Top</button>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan porta sollicitudin. Duis vitae libero pellentesque, dapibus nunc nec, egestas purus. Sed ultrices at ipsum vel dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla ligula sem, condimentum ut eleifend
    ut, pharetra a quam. Curabitur sed fringilla velit. Nullam placerat justo sed nisi venenatis aliquet. In odio libero, faucibus sed velit nec, accumsan iaculis justo. Vestibulum vel rhoncus sapien. Fusce a convallis sapien. Pellentesque eu luctus orci.
    Aliquam dictum massa eget nunc feugiat, eu tempor urna feugiat. Proin ornare magna sed magna venenatis, sit amet gravida ipsum ullamcorper. Vivamus sit amet turpis maximus, venenatis metus quis, facilisis felis. Donec maximus, mi vitae tempor tincidunt,
    nibh nulla dapibus tellus, sit amet aliquam eros mi quis odio. Integer sodales elit sodales ante tempus, ac posuere nisi pellentesque.
  </p>
  <p>
    Duis ut porttitor nisl. Fusce laoreet sodales justo, eu consectetur lacus malesuada ut. Etiam tempus leo id est vestibulum, non finibus tortor dignissim. In nunc dui, volutpat at rhoncus ut, sollicitudin vel libero. Nulla eget nisl imperdiet, varius odio
    vel, pellentesque urna. Donec ornare commodo augue, non malesuada tortor eleifend et. Maecenas sollicitudin fringilla ex, ac aliquam lacus mollis vel. Maecenas faucibus hendrerit purus in laoreet. Nulla maximus varius risus eu sagittis. In urna quam,
    iaculis lacinia turpis eu, consectetur congue sapien. Curabitur eget efficitur eros.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed dictum nulla vitae sapien ornare lacinia. Curabitur eu augue in libero sodales cursus. Sed in consectetur augue. Curabitur vitae sagittis arcu, id malesuada felis. Curabitur efficitur non risus ut placerat. Aliquam commodo rutrum eleifend. Mauris
    a consectetur est. Maecenas semper justo non tristique porta. In eget mauris augue.
  </p>
  <p>
    Sed lacus mi, ultrices ac condimentum sed, eleifend id est. Aenean dapibus sem libero, eget dapibus odio varius sed. Praesent ac elit porta, aliquet tortor ac, aliquet mauris. Sed pharetra tellus sed nunc euismod, ut euismod quam tempus. Nunc rhoncus
    diam ut commodo faucibus. Curabitur et diam vel nulla porta viverra semper nec velit. Donec placerat mi consectetur tortor porta, ac dignissim tellus sollicitudin. Ut viverra sem ut aliquam vulputate. Morbi sagittis viverra commodo. Suspendisse arcu
    sem, consectetur non aliquam id, blandit sit amet quam. In cursus nisl et fermentum eleifend. Curabitur nec imperdiet purus, vel dapibus lorem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Pellentesque et purus ac nisi suscipit feugiat id nec risus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean ornare scelerisque congue. Duis ac velit et metus suscipit auctor. Cras et tellus et ante vehicula
    tincidunt quis at sem. Nunc pharetra et lorem sit amet varius. Proin ultrices, sapien a feugiat ornare, augue enim pretium velit, ac vehicula nibh diam convallis tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac
    turpis egestas.
  </p>
  <button class="btn">Get scroll Top</button>
</div>
```